# "error: invalid operands to binary expression" involving maps

Tags: c++, vector

So I have this code that I am working on for a project.

```
bool openFile(string &fileInput, map<queue<string>,
          vector<string>>&myMap, int&nGram, queue<string>&myQueue) {
    string word;
    string temp;
    ifstream infile(fileInput);
    if (!(infile.is_open())) {
        cout << "Invalid file, try again\n";
        return false;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<nGram-1; i++) {
        infile >> word;
        myQueue.push(word);
    }
    queue<string>copyQueue = myQueue;
    while (!infile.eof()){
        infile >> word; //last word =okay
        myMap[myQueue].push_back(word); //okay has been pushed as a val
        myQueue.push(word); //okay is also now key
        myQueue.pop();
    }
    while(!copyQueue.empty()) {
        myMap[myQueue].push_back(copyQueue.front());
        myQueue.push(copyQueue.front());
        copyQueue.pop();
        myQueue.pop();
    }
    for (auto &e : myMap) {
      cout << e.first << " " << e.second <<
      cout << endl;
    }
    return true;}
```

I get this error.

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream'
  (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const std::queue<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
  std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::deque<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
  std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >,
  std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>
  > > > >')
```

At the moment, I am just trying to print out the keys and values of my map. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can print out the keys and values?

Comment: `queue` does not have an `operator<<`.

Comment: Look at the two `cout` lines in your `for (auto &e : myMap)` loop,

Comment: u r trying to copy vectors and queues using the operator << and there is no operator `<<` defined to take a vector or queue as a second argument.

Comment: Try this simplification: Ignore the map and simply pick a key and value that could be put into the map. Define a variable to hold the key and one to hold the value. Try to stream those variables. *Same error, right? Good. This did not solve your issue, but it did remove a lot of noise. For example, both the file and the map are irrelevant to your issue.*

Comment: Unrelated: `while (!infile.eof()) { infile >> word; ...` should be `while (infile >> word) { ...`.